# Как сделать так, чтобы бот для бесед в вк на Python присылал запись со стены той или иной группы

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Как сделать так, чтобы бот для бесед в вк на питоне присылал запись со стены той или иной группы в беседу?
https://vk.com/dev/wall.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам надо отправить рандомную запись со стены группы/пользователя, то можно воспользоваться методом execute:

```
import vk_api
vk= vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
def send_random_post(from_id,chat_id,message=''):
    code = '''var owner_id = %i;
var chat_id=%i;
var msg = "%s";
var count = API.wall.get({owner_id:owner_id}).count;
var offset = API.apps.getRandomInt({max:count-1});
var post = API.wall.get({owner_id:owner_id,offset:offset});
return API.messages.send({message:msg,chat_id:chat_id,attachment:"wall"+owner_id+"_"+post.items[0].id,random_id:API.apps.getRandomInt({max:9999999999})});
'''
    return vk.method("execute",{"code":code%(from_id,chat_id,message)})
from_id = 1#id группы/пользователя у которой надо брать записи. Для групп id отрицательный
chat_id = 12 # id чата
msg_id = send_random_post(from_id ,chat_id ,"держи рандомную запись!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный ниже код, я писал когда-то для себя. Он присылает на указанный id новые записи из подключенной группы. Таким образом нельзя брать посты из чужой группы.

Если хотите какой-то другой механизм работы - думайте, как вы будете получать wall_id поста, исходя из ваших нужд и возможностей.

Импорт необходимых модулей:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import random
```

Функция для отправки поста:

```
def send(user_id, attachment):
    random_id = random.randint(-2147483648, +2147483648)
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=user_id,
        random_id=random_id,
        message="Новый пост в группе!",
        attachment=attachment
        )
```

Сам код:

```
vk_session_group = vk_api.VkApi(token='ТОКЕН') # Токен группы
vk = vk_session_group.get_api()
longpoll_group = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session_group, 12345)  # ID группы

user_id = 12345678  # Кому отправлять репост

for event in longpoll_group.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.WALL_POST_NEW:
        id_ = event.object['id']
        owner_id_ = event.group_id
        wall_id = f'wall-{owner_id_}_{id_}'
        print('Новый пост! - ', wall_id)
        attachment = wall_id
        send(user_id, attachment)
```